# How to find all indices in a 2-D matrix where pandas data frame has non-NA values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using a large **2-D** pandas dataframe for collaborative filtering algorithm and want to create a list of lists which provides indices of all the **non-NA** values from a 2-D pandas Dataframe.

The 2-D dataframe is like:

```
    0        1        2
0   1        NA       2
1   NA       5        NA
2   NA       NA       NA
3   1        3        4
4   4        NA       1
```

The Expected output list is follows (I made a mistake in mentioning the expected output in origional post and have corrected it):

```
[[0,0], [0,2], [1,1], [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [4,0], [4,2]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected output contains indices where there **are** `NaN` values.

To get them, use: `np.argwhere(np.isnan(df.values)).tolist()`

Or if you want indices of **not NaN** elements, use:

```
np.argwhere(~np.isnan(df.values)).tolist()
```

Comment: I made a mistake in expected output list, I have corrected it